# Couchdb http POST request with sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, couchdb

I'm trying to make a POST request to couchdb with sockets but it doesn't work, I get no response and the program doesn't end. What's wrong?

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5984);
    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
    wr.write("POST /meteo/ HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    wr.write("Content-Length: 245\r\n");
    wr.write("Content-Type: application/json\r\n");
    wr.write("\r\n");

    wr.write(json.toString());//json is a JsonObject
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
       String line;
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the service with something like Telnet to check what the response should be to the HTTP request?